# 一张网页 or 一个网页 ("a webpage"): which is the better choice of measure word, and why?

Tags: difference, measure-word

I just want to say "a webpage", and the two natural options are

> 一**个**网页
>   一**张**网页

It's not hard to find examples of both:

> 访问**一个网页**的全过程<sup>[[src]](https://www.cnblogs.com/viviane/p/10515104.html)</sup>
>   我的第**一张网页**范例<sup>[[src]](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/bf7e47ac690203d8ce2f0066f5335a8102d266ee.html)</sup>

It seems natural to use the measure word 张 in conjunction with 页 (page), but the situation might be different with a 网页 (webpage), so I guess I should go with 个.

It's also possible there's a distinction I'm unaware of.  It's also possible there's another, more suitable measure word I'm unaware of.

**Question**: Which is the better choice of measure word, and why?

What I'm trying to write is:

> 比如一「个/张」网页建议...
>   For example, one webpage suggests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "web page" (网页) is not actually a sheet of paper but a section of a web site (网站).

On any 'web page' of a site, you can access all other pages within the site,  therefore 个 is the correct classifier for 网页

However, if you print a web page, you'd get "a web page print out" (一张网页的打印输出)